# Debian - Restore a Timezone File

Tags: debian, symlink, timezone, restore

So, I just screwed up a timezone file on my Debian system because I pointed it as a link to /etc/localtime vs. pointing /etc/localtime to it. Specifically, /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Puerto_Rico.

I'm obviously way too deep to reinstall the server for the sake of one file. Where can I find and restore just this one file?

I'm using SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
apt-get install --reinstall tzdata
```

### Background

To know which package contains the file you damaged, you could do a

```
dlocate -S /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Puerto_Rico
```

or

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Puerto_Rico
```

which will tell you that the file is in the package `tzdata`.

Once you know that, it's just a matter of telling the package manager to reinstall that package.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! :D  .. wish I knew more Linux